# Vectorizing Pyspark Geodistance Calculation

Tags: python, pyspark, vectorization, databricks

I have 2 datasets:

df: {'key':int, 'latitude':num, 'longitude':num}
cent: {'latitude':num, 'longitude':num, 'income': num}

I need basically to calculate the distance between each row in df and each row in cent, and when the distance is <= 5000 meters, sum the income.

The output needs to be the sum of income for every distance <= 5000 meters.

I have coded a non-vectorized solution, as below, which seems to work, but it takes forever. I need help to vectorize it. I don't even know where to start.

I'm doing all this in databricks, using pyspark.

Thank you!

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians

def calcdist(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):  # funcao calcula distancia em metros entre dois pontos
  R = 6371
  lat1 = radians(lat1)
  lon1 = radians(lon1)
  lat2 = radians(lat2)
  lon2 = radians(lon2)
  dlon = lon2 - lon1
  dlat = lat2 - lat1
  a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
  c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
  distance = R * c * 1000
  return(distance)

rdd = []
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

for row in df.toLocalIterator():
  for row2 in cent.toLocalIterator():
    d = calcdist(lat1 = float(row.lat), lon1 = float(row.lon), lat2 = float(row2.latitude), lon2 = float(row2.longitude))
    if (d is not None and d <= 5000):
      x = x + row2.income * row2.pop
      y = y + row2.pop
      z = z + row2.houses
    else:
      x = x + 0
      y = y + 0
      z = z + 0
  rdd.append((row.key, x, y, z))
  x = 0
  y = 0
  z = 0

rdd = sc.parallelize(rdd)

df2=rdd.toDF(['id','soma_faixa_renda', 'total_pop', 'total_houses'])

df2.show()
```

Comment: Hi Erick, can you provide few examples of your data? Seems like this can be done using `join` and `udf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have 2 dataframe with columns `[id, latitude1, longtitude1]` and `[latitude2, longtitude2, income]` (seem like `key` is not a good column name, might throw some error). First, you can make `udf` function to calculate distance:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import *
calcdist_udf = fn.udf(calcdist, returnType=DoubleType())
```

Then, you can cross join dataframe and apply created `udf` function to calculate distance

```
df_join = df.crossJoin(cent)
df_dist = df_join.select(fn.col('id'), fn.col('income'), 
                         calcdist_udf('latitude1', 'longtitude1', 'latitude2', 'longtitude2').alias('distance'))
df_dist.cache() # cache first because of bug in Spark
```

Now, you have a dataframe with the calculated distance. Just filter row with low distance and aggregate as you want

```
df_agg = df_dist.where(df_dist['distance'] <= 5000).groupby('id').agg(fn.sum('income').alias('sum_income'), fn.count('income').alias('n_house'))
df_agg_pandas = df_agg.toPandas() # save to pandas dataframe
```

Comment: @ErickFarias, glad to hear that!